# Call must be made on main thread i can get the data but when i want it to show error message it crashes

Tags: swift, error-handling, uialertcontroller, dispatch-queue, networkonmainthread

**StartScreenVC**

```
import UIKit

class StartScreenVC: UIViewController {
    
    private var apiService = ApiService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadPopularMoviesData()
    }

    private func loadPopularMoviesData() {
        apiService.getPopularMoviesData { [weak self] (result) in
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let listOf):
                print(result)
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.showAlertWith(title: "Could not connect!", message: "Plese check your internet connection \n or try again later")
                print("Error processing json data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Show Alert
    
    func showAlertWith(title: String, message: String, style: UIAlertController.Style = .alert) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            alertController.addAction(action)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

**ApiService**

```
import Foundation

class ApiService {
    
    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    
    // MARK: - Get popular movies data
    func getPopularMoviesData(completion: @escaping (Result<MovieData, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let popularMoviesURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=4e0be2c22f7268edffde97481d49064a&language=en-US&page=1"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: popularMoviesURL) else {return}
        
        // Create URL Session - work on the background
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // Handle Error
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                print("DataTask error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                // Handle Empty Response
                print("Empty Response")
                return
            }
            print("Response status code: \(response.statusCode)")
            
            guard let data = data else {
                // Hndle Empty Data
                print("Empty Data")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                // Parse the data
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(MovieData.self, from: data)
                
                // Back to the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(jsonData))
                }
            } catch let error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
```

The error I got 'Call must be made on main thread'

I'm getting the data without any problems, but the application I want to give an error crashes.

Is there a bug in the dispatchQueue parts?

Why am I getting an error here?

What I want to do is bring the error message to the screen without any problems, when the internet is cut off or the api is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `ApiService` there are two calls to `completion` which do not happen on the main thread, specifically in the failure cases. Try wrapping them in `DispatchQueue.main` as well and see if it works.

In my opinion, it should not be the responsibility of the `ApiService` to make sure your view controller code runs on the main thread. A more solid approach would be to wrap completion code in `DispatchQueue.main`:

```swift
private func loadPopularMoviesData() {
    apiService.getPopularMoviesData { [weak self] (result) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .success(let listOf):
                print(result)
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.showAlertWith(title: "Could not connect!", message: "Plese check your internet connection \n or try again later")
                print("Error processing json data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you jack your answer worked and i understood. Thanks for the nice and simple explanation.